# Why does a near UV laser show as a green path in tap water?

Tags: optics, atomic-physics, water, laser, laser-interaction

i am using a 405nm laser and shining through a glass with regular tap water, also i noticed that it shows as an almost white path in the thick glass bottom, what causes this?
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is *luminescence*.

The atoms in the media first absorb the relatively high-energy UV radiation.  Some of the energy that was absorbed then finds its way elsewhere, often to thermal energy via inter-molecular collisions slightly raising the temperature of the fluid.  This leaves the molecule with less energy.   Then all (or most) of that remaining energy is emitted as light of a lower frequency (green light in this case) and the molecule returns to its ground state.

Comment: Yes, luminescence, but that kind of luminescence is more specifically known as _[fluorescence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluorescence)_